# Initializing struct member of type struct pointer to null

Tags: c

I'm having an issue with assigning a null value to a pointer to a struct member (that is also a pointer to a struct). The following code correctly sets the `headNode->right` variable equal to null, but not the `headNode->left` variable.

```
typedef struct node {
    char *key;
    int frequency;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *parent;
} node;


void addKey(char key[]) {
    extern node *headNode;
    node *newNode;

    if (headNode != NULL) {
        printf("Head node is initialized\n");
        if (headNode->left != NULL) printf("    Left is not null\n");
        if (headNode->right != NULL) printf("    Right is not null\n");
    }


    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node*));
    newNode->key = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(key) + 1));
    newNode->left = malloc(sizeof(node*));
    newNode->right = malloc(sizeof(node*));
    newNode->parent = malloc(sizeof(node*));


    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->frequency = 1;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    strcpy(newNode->key, key);

    // If this is the first node, assign it as the root
    if (headNode == NULL) {
        newNode->parent = NULL;
        headNode = newNode;
        return;
    }
}
```

However, if I add the following two lines right before the `return` statement, it works correctly.

```
if (headNode->left == NULL) printf("L is null\n");
else printf("L is NOT null\n");
```

I don't understand how an if statement can make a difference. There is nowhere else that assigns or changes the value of this variable anywhere else in my code.

Comment: *if I add the following two lines right before the last return statement* – There is only one `return` statement that is within an `if` that establishes that `headNode == NULL`!?

Comment: I try to avoid this sort of syntax: `newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL` because the evaluation order makes a difference and it's confusing. And why do you set `newNode->right = NULL` two lines later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a step back. There are a number of serious mistakes here.

You declare a pointer to a `node`:

`node *newNode;`

So far, so good. However, when you try to allocate memory for this new node, you only allocate enough to store a pointer, instead of the node itself:

`newNode = malloc(sizeof(node*));`

You already have storage for the pointer: `newNode`.

Change this line to:

`newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));`

A little later you make three more unnecessary calls to `malloc`:

```
newNode->left = malloc(sizeof(node*));
newNode->right = malloc(sizeof(node*));
newNode->parent = malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

If you had requested enough memory (i.e. `sizeof(node)`) in the previous call, there would be no need to allocate any more memory for these internal fields. You would already have memory for them; it would already exists at the address pointed to by `newNode`.

Worse still, you then go on to leak memory on the next line:

`newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;`

Here you are throwing away the addresses of the memory you allocated unnecessarily.

I think you need to read up on memory management further before we can troubleshoot this problem for you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I should have realized that I needed to allocate enough memory for the struct rather than the pointer for newNode. I remember figuring that out before, I just completely blanked. As for the three unnecessary malloc calls, that was from me trying to figure it out based off of other SO posts. Your explanation makes sense why that was unnecessary though. In regards to the memory leak; how would I deal with that? I need to have those values set to NULL until the nodes they will eventually point to are created. Thank you so much again for your response.

Comment: @Jake no problem. Sorry if my reply sounded harsh. It looks like you're not comfortable with pointers yet - that's cool, they're one of C's trickier concepts. But they're also really dangerous in the wrong hands, so it's worth making sure this stuff is second-nature before trying to build trees and lists etc.

Comment: Sorry, I posted that early by accident and added an edit onto it. And no worries, I definitely know I need to get a better understanding of them.

Comment: Regarding the memory leak, if you simply use `malloc(sizeof(node))` in the first place, you can set `newNode->left` and `newNode->right` to `NULL` just as you have done. Those values will simply be zeros in the block of memory pointed to by `newNode`. Later, when you want to call `free(newNode)` you'll need to check if `newNode->left` and `newNode->right` are non-`NULL`, and deal with them first (if they are non-`NULL` they will point to _different_ blocks of memory that need to be `free`d separately. This stuff should be wrapped up in a `deleteNode` function.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

All the `malloc(sizeof(node*))` should be `malloc(sizeof(node))`. You're only alloocating enough space for a pointer, not the whole structure. This is causing undefined behavior with all the following code that indirects through these pointers.